# I cant put the pictures and text inline properly

Tags: html, css

how can I put text beside picture without disturbing the other content?

this is a header

## html

```
 <div>
    <img src="logo.ico" width="300px" height="200px" alt="logo"/>
    <h1 class="header">Movies19</h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: You can use the following style="float:left; padding-right: 10px" or float: right; padding-left: 10px in the img tag. This will have both the image and Content in same line. Padding is used to give some breathing space between image and content.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the two elements in the div to `display:inline-block` tag

```css
.line>* {
  display: inline-block;
}
h1 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" width="300px" height="200px" alt="logo" />
  <h1 class="header">Mo</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<style type="text/css">
   img {
    display: inline-block;
   }
</style>
```

look at this link it may help more:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_img_default_css

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <img src="logo.ico" width="300px" height="200px" alt="logo" />
 </td>
 <td>
    <h1 class="header">Movies19</h1>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```